# Keep First and Last entry of a Duplicate in a Dataframe Column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, duplicates

I have a big dataframe with many duplicates in it. I want to keep the first and last entry of each duplicate but drop every duplicate in between.

I've already tried to get this done by using df.drop_duplicates with the parameters 'first' and 'last' to get two dataframes and then merge them again to one df so I have the first and last entry, but that didn't work.

```
df_first = df
df_last = df

df_first['Path'].drop_duplicates(keep='first', inplace=True)
df_last['Path'].drop_duplicates(keep='last', inplace=True)
```

Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: Could you share a sample and expected output??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.nth`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.nth.html) for avoid duplicates if group with length is `1`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
         'a':[5,3,6,9,2,4],
         'Path':list('aaabbc')
})
print(df)
   a Path
0  5    a
1  3    a
2  6    a
3  9    b
4  2    b
5  4    c

df = df.groupby('Path').nth([0, -1])
print (df)
      a
Path   
a     5
a     6
b     9
b     2
c     4
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your fast response, worked out perfectly fine! :-)

Answer (score 0):

**Using group by.nth which is an Updated code from previous solution to get nth entry

```
def keep_second_dup(duplicate):
        duplicate[Columnname]=duplicate[Columnname'].value_counts()
        second_duplicate=duplicate[duplicate['Count']>=1]
        residual=duplicate[duplicate['Count']==1]
        sec=second_duplicated.groupby([Columnname]).nth([1]).reset_index()
        final_data=pd.concat([sec,residual])
        final_data.drop('Count',axis=1,inplace=True)
        return final_data
```